# store numeric value in number(x,y) format without decimal in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table named `table1` in which data is import through sql loader.

I have a column named `totalAvg number(5,2)`.

In csv file I have the data without decimal like: 10000, 8000 etc.

I want to convert data value like 10000 -> 100.00 , 8000 -> 80.00 before inserting data into data table.

Comment: What do you mean by without decimal ?

Comment: Why not divide `totalAvg/100` in loader file? So it will  insert as `100.00`,`80.00` etc.

Comment: totalAvg/100 is generating error.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

If the column is already a number, it doesn't have any intrinsic formatting - you don't store formatted strings, you store just a numeric value. Just store 100, 80, etc. (i.e. divide the number by 100).

If you want it formatted, you apply the format *when you display the results* - e.g. when you query you can `SELECT TO_CHAR(totalAvg, 'fm999G990D00') FROM table1` which will format the numbers like `100.00`, `80.00` etc.